# Unable to write into Google Cloud storage from VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run the following code on my GCP VM instance.

```
!gsutil cp 'text.csv' 'gs://BucketName/folderName/'
```

I am getting the error message `AccessDeniedException: 403 XXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to mybucket`

I have tried to edit IAM access rights and give the service account the storage admin rights but I still could'nt resolve this.

i also run the following checks:

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy Project-ID
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-XXXXX@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/compute.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:XXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:XXXXX@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:service-XXXXX@sourcerepo-service-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - user:myemail@company.com
  role: roles/owner
- members:
  - user:mycolleagueemail@company.com
  role: roles/resourcemanager.projectOwnerInvitee
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-XXXX@sourcerepo-service-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/sourcerepo.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:XXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:XXXXXX@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:service-XXXXX@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:service-XXXXXX@sourcerepo-service-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - user:myemail@company.com
  role: roles/storage.admin
etag: BwWHPRO76cr=
version: 1
```

I am pretty new to GCP, so any advice/help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For the Compute Engine VM instance, what scopes did you assign when you created the instance? Make sure that you have Cloud Storage set to read-write or full.

Comment: Hi, I have already set it to be "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" for my VM instance. but  still getting this issue.

Comment: Next step check the actual permissions assigned to the service account: `gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID`

Comment: Note: `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` does NOT give you all permissions. Only the ones assigned to the service account member for the project. The VM and Bucket need to be in the same project OR you need to assign the service account to each project.

Comment: PROJECT_ID is the project ID that owns the bucket.

Comment: yes, already granted member to status and permission to my account. Also, i only have one project and i am the owner for project and bucket. i dont understand why being the owner and creator of this project and yet i cant access it

Comment: What is the output of the command? Edit your question with the details.

Comment: Your service account has more than enough permissions (owner and object.admin). The only thing left is 1) You have not set the scopes correctly on the VM instance (try shutting down and manually editing the scopes to allow storage read-write). 2) The bucket is owned by a different project (which you verified is not possible). Note: It does not matter if you are the owner, all that matters is the service accounts permissions. The service account is accessing the bucket, not your identity.

Comment: Another possibility is you have spelled the bucket name wrong and the bucket is owned by someone else.